# Modified Structure of RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, distributed-computing, bigdata

I am new to spark/scala.

```
val First: RDD[((Short, String), (Int, Double, Int))]
```

This is structure of RDD. I want to modified this sturcture something like bellow:

```
val First: RDD[(Short, String , Int, Double, Int)]
```

Because I am having another RDD with different Structure and I want to UNION both this RDD. (Structure must be same in UNION operation).

Please Suggest me an option.

Comment: No sweat: `First.map { case ((x,y),(z,w)) => (x,y,z,w) }`

Comment: @Alec I tried this but as amount of data is large so this will slow down performance. Because Map will iterate the data one by one.

Comment: Please suggest me some solution where I can change structure without iterating data

Comment: Actually, it won't. Transformations like `map` are performed lazily in Spark. The `map` ends up being calculated at the same time as whatever action completes the chain of transformations - there is no intermediate step. The slowdown would anyways be parallelized over your cluster, so if your cluster can't handle even this, it probably won't be able to handle whatever else you are planning on doing afterwards...

Comment: @Alec my updated answer pretty much agrees with you (right? :) ), so Darshan don't get confused, I really agree with Alec!

Comment: @gsamaras Yep. We are saying the same thing.

Comment: @Alec Thank you for your support. I have written other code as well but I was thinking to remove this extra `Map` just to change structure of RDD.
So that i can improve performance.

Comment: I agree with both of you, But 10 seconds is also important for me. You can understand what i mean to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map your data, like this:

```
First.map{ case ( (x, y), (k, z, w) ) => (x, y, k, z, w) }
```

and in order to write this map function, you have to check the format of your  RDD, `((Short, String), (Int, Double, Int))`, which is what I wrote as `(x, y), (k, z, w)`, and then write the format you want in the right side of `=>`.

---

Edit for the comment:

> As Map will iterate data one by one

[spark](/questions/tagged/spark) applies the transformation only when an action occurs, so `map()` works really well, in a distributed manner. Every partition will apply the map function in its data.

That's a not very costly operation though, so don't focus on that, focus on your join, which is the heavy operation. A map function should be something cheap, if you have the corresponding resources in your cluster, for your amount of data.

Comment: Do you have any other option to Modified structure without iteration(As Map will iterate data one by one)